# How can I plot real time signal in pyqt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I want to plot real time signal using pyqt. Can any one tell me how can I do it? What is the procedure I need to follow for real time signal plotting? Any suggestion with basic examples is most appreciable.

Comment: What are the exact requirements? I believe no software out there really does real time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signal in PyQt is just a call to another callable object (method, function, functor), with some data. It is not the same as an electronic signal from, say, a USB connector.

However, if you have a driver that reads a USB device's state at some frequency F, then all you would need is a QApplication instance, with a QWindow instance that has a method that gets called at a frequency similar to F using QTimer, and that method emits a custom signal with some data whenever the data has changed. You would connect the PyQt signal to a method on, say, on a custom matplotlib plot object that adds the point to the plot.

The above is not the only approach. There are many ways to do this and the specifics depend on your specifics. Look for those classes (QApplication, QWindow, QTimer), and matplotlib package, look at some PyQt examples that come with the PyQt installation, try your own code, then if needed post again specific questions with the code you tried.